# SQL Server Print Blank Line Without Space

Tags: sql, sql-server, printing

In SQL Server 2005, I want to print out a blank line with the PRINT statement, however, when I run

```
PRINT ''
```

it actually prints a line with a single space.

Does anyone know if it's possible to just print a blank line without the space?

If I print a new line character, it doesn't print a space, but I end up with two new lines.

Answer (score 8):

You could just add a newline on your previous print statement, if you have one.

Instead of:

```
PRINT 'BLABLABLA'
PRINT ''
```

You could write:

```
PRINT 'BLABLABLA
' <- the string finishes here!
```

Answer (score 5):

Very similar to the other suggestion here, this seems to work:

```
print '
'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
-- Search the web for: SQL PRINT NewLine
-- What you'll end up finding:

DECLARE @CR AS CHAR(1)    -- Carriage Return (CR)
DECLARE @LF AS CHAR(1)    -- Line Feed (LF)
DECLARE @CrLf AS CHAR(2)  -- Carriage Return / Line Feed

SET @CR = CHAR(10)
SET @LF = CHAR(13)
SET @CrLf = @CR + @LF

PRINT '--==--==--==--==--=='
PRINT @CrLf + 'Use variables as you see fit' + @CrLf
PRINT '--==--==--==--==--=='

-- AntGut
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you encode the BACKSPACE character and PRINT that out?

UPDATE: PRINT ''  + CHAR(8) doesn't seem to go down particularly well :(

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way around this, it is the way the print statement works

Answer (score 0):

This suggests that you want to print a blank message. Are you sure that this is your intention? The Print statement actually sends a message to the error/message-handling mechanism that then transfers it to the calling application.